# Ssis find row with max value in column

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, etl, transformation

I need help with finding row with newest date in ssis. I have excel file and I need to find row with newest date in column "update_date" and then import that row in database. How can I find just that one row using ssis? For example I have a row with columns A, B, C and Update_Date and lets say my excel file looks like this:

```
T1, T1, T1, 1.1.2023
T2, T2, T2, 2.2.2023
T3, T3, T3, 3.3.2023
```

I need to find the third row and import only that row in database.

I tried using conditional split but cant use Max(date) as max cant be used in conditional splitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this and let me know if It solves your problem.

You can query excel source by picking up sql command from Data Access Mode.

[image: SQL Command Source]

Here you can use Sheetname as Database table, enclosed in square brackets. Please do not forget to add a $ sign after sheet name, and you can also define a range if your data resides in certain cells in excel.

Then create an OLE DB destination table to send that row to your table in dest db.

I hope It solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you need `TOP` in your query to restrict the result after ordering the data as follows:

```
SELECT TOP(1) a, b, c, updated_date
  FROM your_table
ORDER BY updated_date DESC;
```

Comment: I know how to sort it using ssis but how can I use query after that? Also I dont have table, after importing excel i only have rows with values in columns

Answer (score 0):

Import all rows from excel to a temp ("staging") table in the database. Then use another data flow task to query this temp table as suggested, taking only one needed row, and saving it to the final destination.